# Mail Functionality in PHP

Tags: php

Hi,

i have my office outlook so that i can send mail to any person's id. 
the problem is that i am working on php sciprt and using mail function to send mails. i have installed WAMP on my desktop pc to run the php script. i want to check the php mail functionality but i am not aware how to configure my office outlook with my local WAMP sever. This is following code i am using for send mails in php script. please give me solution  :

```
   <?php
    $to = "someone@example.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "someonelse@example.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";

?>
```

Comment: Hope u using Windows pc...

Answer (score 2):

Change your SMTP settings in `php.ini`

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = "mail.yourdomain.com"
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = "port number"

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = "name@yourdomain.com"
```

**References:**

[`Send mail through wamp`](http://www.webdevtuts.net/quicktips/how-to-send-emails-using-your-localhost-wamp-mamp-or-xampp/)

[`one more reference`](http://www.skylinedesign.co.ke/send-email-from-local-php-wampserver/)

[`send mail fro localhost`](http://www.blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/)

Answer (score 1):

1). You Shd set the Email SMTP and mail settings in php.ini from **OutLook**.

Just Check here for getting those [Configs of Outlook](http://products.secureserver.net/email/email_outlook.htm)

2). [Change in **PHP.ini**](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10307560-CONFIGURING-php.ini-%28Setting-the-SMTP%29!!!)

3). or -(+1 Michel) can also set smtp with PHP Script

```
ini_set("SMTP", "mail.server.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the SMTP settings in your php configuration file, or use `ini_set` to set them temporarily.

EDIT: This is how you set them temporarily (until the end of the script).

```
ini_set("SMTP", "mail.server.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
```

Comment: how to set ini_set temporarily.

Comment: can you just tell me how will i check SMTP sever domain and smtp_port?

Comment: the current settings? either using `phpinfo()` or `ini_get()`

Comment: Just look inside your php.ini file, or use `ini_get`, e.g. `echo ini_get('SMTP')`

Comment: my question is how will i know what mail sever domain i shud use..in php.in its localhost and port is 25..